# How do I go "async all the way down" with Node Express?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, async-await

I have many async functions in my system, so I need to go "async all the way down", which is to the point where the `http.Server` and `express.Application` app are created.

*(This is unavoidable in an async system - there will be many async routines which are needed in constructors, which cannot be done, and so we need to use async factory functions instead, which lead to async creep all the way down to the entry point.)*

But I'm not sure of the Node/TypeScript syntax to use to bootstrap the app.

My main entry point is `System.ts`:

```
class default export System {

  public constructor() {
    // init Express.Application
    // init http.Server
    // init other parts of the system
  }

  public async start(): Promise<void> {
    // start the system asynchronously
    // start listening with http.Server
  }

}
```

Then I have a bootstrapping module `Main.ts`:

```
import System from "./System"
const system = new System();
export default ???;                      // PROBLEM IS HERE
```

Which should be run:

```
node ./dist/Main.js
```

But I'm not sure what to use in the export line. I tried all these:

```
export default await system.start();     // doesn't compile (obviously)
export default system.start();           // doesn't seem right
export default system.start().then();    // this works *maybe*
```

The last line works based on a smoke test - but I'm not sure if that's the way to do it, and whether there's something down the line that may fail.

What is the canonical way to start an asynchronous node app?

---

UPDATE
Based on @JacobGillespie's answer, the `Main.ts` bootstrapping module is now:

```
import System from "./System"
new System().start().then();
//new System().start().catch(e => console.error(e));  // alternative
```

In my case, `System.ts` has handlers for errors and unhandled promises, and does logging (otherwise use the "alternative" line). So the bootstrapping module just bootstraps the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` / `await` here are operating on promises, so you essentially want to "start" the promise by calling `.then` or `.catch`.

My go-to snippet for this is creating an async `run` or `main` function, then attaching error handling to the process, something like this:

```
async function run() {
  // run the app, you can await stuff in here
}

run().catch(err => {
  console.error(err.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

In your case that would look like (`Main.ts`):

```
import System from "./System"

async function run() {
  const system = new System()
  await system.start()
}

run().catch(err => {
  console.error(err.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

You don't need to export anything since this module file isn't being imported anywhere else (it's the entry file).

You can just call `system.then()` or `system.catch()`, but personally I like the `async function run()` pattern since you may need to coordinate more than one async thing in the future and this makes the code more explicit.

Comment: Thanks Jacob! Assuming that all my async orchestration is already within my `System` class, as well as error handling, then could I simplify the bootstrapping module to something like `system.start().then();` - is that "safe"?

Comment: The only potential issue there is if something throws an error inside the `system` that isn't caught, it will be considered an uncaught promise exception. Calling `.catch()` starts a promise just the same as `.then()`, so I'd change that to be `system.start().catch(err => { ... })`, and you probably want to log the error and exit the process with an error code inside that error handler.

Comment: You did mention "as well as error handling" so you are correct that `.then()` is fine _if_ you're totally sure everything is handled, but there's always the "what if there's an error in the error handler" case, so having the final check is nice.

Comment: Yeah, but I have an uncaught promise handler, other error handling, and logging, within `System.ts` already... That is the "entry point", and I only need to start/bootstrap it.

Answer (score 0):

```
system.start().then() => {
    value => export default value
}
```

In my opinion, a better way would be:
System.ts:

```
function System():Promise<string>{
    //setup express and the server
    return new Promise((res,rej) => {
        //the server var is just the http server instance
        server.listen(8000,() => resolve("server created"));
    });
}
export {System}
```

And then in Main.ts:

```
import {System} from "yourpath"
```

And then:

```
System().then(() => {
    //code runs when server is created
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `[ts] An export assignment can only be used in a module.`

Comment: Well then,  what exactly do you want to export? The value the promise resolves to? The promise itself? I mean, what script do you want to import your stuff?   If you only want to run code after the server is made, you may just export the promise, and in the script wich imports it, use .then() to do your code, also, i dont think you need a class for this, functions would be enaught

Comment: I want to run the async app from the shell

Comment: Thanks! This seems like a good way to do it, for those who prefer the functional approach and promises.

Comment: Haha not a backhanded compliment at all, I meant that I prefer classes and async/await, but most node devs prefer functional and promises, so it's a good alternative answer! Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, a while ago i made a quick library called translucid, wich basically does exactly this for you (+some other common used code),   https://www.npmjs.com/package/translucid , its not something profesional, i just made it so i dont need to write the same and the same code again:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188100/discussion-between-matei-adriel-and-lonix).